# Separar elementos dentro de uma lista para criar uma tabela

Tags: lista

Surgiu uma oportunidade de automatizar uma rotina de trabalho, mas enfrento um problema que gostaria de ajuda.

Rotina:
Uma vez por mês entro em um site e faço a consulta para verificar a data de atualização de mais ou menos 250 normas.
Então usando selenium e BeautifulSoup consegui automatizar este processo.

Problema:
Não estou conseguindo manipular a lista para que fique uma tabela desta forma, mostrada no exemplo abaixo.

Exemplo de como quero que fique:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

note que a `Descrição` está na mesma String que `Norma`, e o `Status` referent a esta `Norma` está no próximo índice, então você tem que percorrer a lista incrementando de 2 em 2. Caso você separe cada resultado em 3 elementos (como o exemplo que você sitou `Norma`,`Descricao`,`Status`) você deverá percorrer o array de 3 em 3, modificando algumas partes do algoritmo abaixo

utilizando a sua variável `dados_norma`:

```
header=['Norma - Descricao','Status']
separador='-'*120
# função auxiliar para formatação da string 
def trunc_string(string:str,l:int,outro_campo:str):
    result=string[:l]+'  |  '+outro_campo+'\n'
    string=string[l:]
    while (l < len(string)):
        result+=string[:l]+'  |  \n'
        string=string[l:]
    return((result+string+(' '*(l-len(string)))+'  |  '))    
# imprimindo cabeçalho
print('{}{}  |  {}\n{}'.format(
    header[0],
    (' '*(100-len(header[0]))),
    header[1],
    separador
))
indice=0    
# imprimindo valores de dados_norma com formatação tabelada
while indice < len(dados_norma):
    print('{}\n{}'.format(
        trunc_string(dados_norma[indice],100,dados_norma[indice+1]),
        separador
    ))
    indice+=2
```